# Происхождение слова «отмутузить»

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Какова этимология глагола «отмутузить»? Связан ли он со словом «тузить»?

Comment: Есть такая этимологическая версия: https://www.proza.ru/2012/07/08/1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, всё-таки не однокоренные,синонимы, связанные общей темой.Оба просторечия из воровского жаргона.

**Тузить** - бить тузом, а потом уже вошло в простонародную речь как просто бить.

Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона (оригинальная орфография)

Тузить кого (иноск.) — колотить кулакомъ (какъ бьютъ тузомъ прочія карты).

Тузила — драчунъ (школьн.).

Ср. *Потузять другъ друга два... господина и ихъ на цугундеръ въ кварталъ.*

Вс. Крестовскій. Сильныя ощущенія подъ Петербургомъ.

Ср. *Онъ... встрѣчался опять съ тѣми пріятелями, которые его тузили, и встрѣчался какъни въ чемъ не бывало: и онъ, какъ говорится, ничего, и онѣ ничего.
Гоголь. Мертвыя души.* 1, 4 (о Ноздревѣ).

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_old/9552/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

МУТУСКИ
- стаpые игpальные каpты
Словарь воровского жаргона. 2012
  https://slovar.cc/sleng/vor/2489117.html

От "мутуски" - мутузить - трепать (карты потрёпанные, потому что в игре ими бьют по лбу проигравших). Карты измутузили и игроков ими мутузят.

А вот часть корня "туз" делает их созвучными, да и  смысл сошёлся, это синонимы, потому и воспринимаются как однокоренные.